# Привязать QThread к QProgressBar и кнопкам

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qthread

Есть простой интерфейс.

Необходимо чтобы при нажатии кнопки 'Start' стартовал прирост 1 единица прогресса в секунду используя обычный метод, например такой:

```
def add_value(prog_bar):
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        prog_bar.setValue(i)
```

а при нажатии 'Stop' прирост останавливался.
**Сделать это необходимо с помощю QThread.**

Мой код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('ProgressBar')
vbx = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
prg_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
prg_bar.setRange(0,100)
button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop')
vbx.addWidget(prg_bar)
vbx.addWidget(button_start)
vbx.addWidget(button_stop)
window.setLayout(vbx)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне кажется, что вам надо определиться и отметить один из вариантов ответов как правильный.

Comment: Обязательно. Я законопослушный оверфловщик.

Comment: К сожалению я так и не понял принцип работы потоков. У меня была проблема, был метод, который наращивал цифру, когда я в этот метод передавал прогрессбар, он просто зависал, и оживал только тогда когда заполнялся на 100%. Я думал потоки смогут решить проблему, и они могут, но я всё еще не знаю как. Но всёравно всем спасибо за помощ, может смогу разобрать ваш код по ниточкам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно наследоваться от QThread и использовать QWaitCondition, QMutex и QThread.sleep для того, чтобы генерировать периодические события:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QWaitCondition, QMutex

import sys

class WoofThread(QThread):

    # Сигнал потока
    signal_woof = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

        # Поле для работы вечного цикла
        self._action = True
        # интервал сна/паузы
        self._timeout = 1

        # объект погружения/пробуждения потока в сон/ из сна
        self._waitCondition = QWaitCondition()

    def run(self):
        mutex = QMutex()

        # Поле-признак того, что пока спать, или просыпаться
        self._wait = True
        self._action = True
        while self._action:
            # Если поступил приказ ждать - ждем
            if self._wait:
                mutex.lock()
                self._waitCondition.wait(mutex)
                mutex.unlock()

            # Спим _timeout - времени
            QThread.sleep(self._timeout)
            # Гав!
            self.signal_woof.emit()

    # Поехали
    def go(self):
        self._wait = False
        self._waitCondition.wakeAll()

    # Погодите
    def wait(self):
        self._wait = True

    # Завершить работу потока
    def cancel(self):
        self._action = False
        self._waitCondition.wakeAll()
```

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

thread = WoofThread()

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle('ProgressBar')
vbx = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
prg_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
prg_bar.setRange(0,100)
prg_bar.setValue(0)

button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')

# Клик вызывает пробуждение и продолжение работы потока
button_start.clicked.connect(thread.go)

button_stop = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop')
# Клик вызывает ожидание потока
button_stop.clicked.connect(thread.wait)

# Получили сигнал из потока - увеличили прогресс на +1
thread.signal_woof.connect(lambda: prg_bar.setValue(prg_bar.value() +1))

vbx.addWidget(prg_bar)
vbx.addWidget(button_start)
vbx.addWidget(button_stop)
window.setLayout(vbx)
window.show()

# Запустили поток
thread.start()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: есть с чего выбрать, но я на пару секунд опередил :)

Comment: @S.Nick всегда хорошо, когда меню на любой вкус )

Comment: Alexander  согласен   `+`

Comment: Надо модуль `sys` ещё импортировать

Comment: Думал получить простенький вариант ) если эти варианты простенькие, тогда мне нужно ещё очень много тренироваться )

Comment: @arachnoden да тут просто все )  Старт - поехали, стоп - стоим, старт - опять поехали и так далее

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started  = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    data     = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int) 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.running = False
        self.num = 0

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def read_data_from_sensor(self):
        self.started.emit()
        QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)                              # Моделируем процесс блокировки
        while self.running and self.num < 100:
            self.num += 1
            self.data.emit(self.num)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)                           
        self.finished.emit()


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Реализация QThread-moveToThread")
        self.resize(400, 300)
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.boton_iniciar = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Начать', self)
        self.boton_iniciar.clicked.connect(self.read_data)

        self.label_data = QtWidgets.QLabel(self, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_data.setText('В ожидании')
        self.label_data.adjustSize()
        
        self.prg_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget) 
        layout.addWidget(self.label_data)        
        layout.addWidget(self.prg_bar)
        layout.addWidget(self.boton_iniciar)

        self._worker = Worker()
        self._worker.started.connect(self.on_started)
        self._worker.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self._worker.data.connect(self.update_label)

        self._thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        self._thread.start()
        self._worker.moveToThread(self._thread)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_started(self):
        """ slot будет вызван, когда начнется сбор данных """
        if self._worker.num == 100:
            self._worker.num = 0
            self.prg_bar.setValue(0)
            self._worker.running = False
        
        self.label_data.setText("Читаем данные")
        self.boton_iniciar.setText("Стоп")
        self.boton_iniciar.setEnabled(True)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        """ slot будет вызван, когда сбор данных закончится """
        self.label_data.setText("В ожидании")
        self.boton_iniciar.setText("Начать")
        self.boton_iniciar.setEnabled(True)
        print("_worker.running: finished", self.prg_bar.value())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def read_data(self):
        """ Начать / остановить чтение при нажатии кнопки """
        print("_worker.running:", self._worker.running)
        self.on_started()
        
        if self._worker.running:
            self._worker.running = False
        else:
            self._worker.running = True
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self._worker.read_data_from_sensor)
        self.boton_iniciar.setEnabled(False)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)  # str
    def update_label(self, data):
        """ Slot будет вызываться при появлении новых данных в метке """
        self.prg_bar.setValue(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = App()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]